# Get many 3d matrices from two 2d matrices (column-wise multiplication)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, multiplication, bsxfun

Is there a faster way to perform the following operation without a loop?

```
n = 2;
m = 1000;
A = rand(n,m);
B = rand(n,m);

C = zeros(n*n,m);
for i = 1 : m
    tmp = A(:,i) * B(:,i)';
    C(:,i) = tmp(:);
end
```

Basically I need to obtain `m` `nxn` matrices with a column-wise matrix multiplication between `A` and `B`. Then I need the vectorization of such matrices.

Comment: `C(:,i)` is a Kronecker product, which can also be calculated by `kron(B(:,i),A(:,i))`. Though, I can't help you any further with vectorizing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically performing elementwise multiplications for all columns in `A` against all columns, but transposed in `B`. You can have one vectorized approach with [`bsxfun(@times,..)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) basically *killing/replacing* those *nasty loops* with `bsxfun`'s powerful internal expansion capability. The implementation would also involve reshape to have it in the same format as `C` and would look something like this -

```
out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2])),n^2,[])
```

**Runtime tests**

This section compares all approaches listed thus far to solve the problem.

Benchmarking code -

```
%// Inputs
n = 2;
m = 1000;
A = rand(n,m);
B = rand(n,m);

num_iter = 5000;

disp('-------------------- For loop NO fuN') %// From OP question
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    C = zeros(n*n,m);
    for i = 1 : m
        tmp = A(:,i) * B(:,i)';
        C(:,i) = tmp(:);
    end
end
toc

disp('-------------------- run run KRON') %'// @lhcgeneva's solution
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    A1 = repmat(A, n, 1);
    B1 = kron(B,ones(n,1));
    D = reshape(A1(:).*B1(:), n*n, m);
end
toc

disp('-------------------- fun fun BSXFUN') %// Proposed in this post
tic
for iter = 1:num_iter
    out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2])),n^2,[]);
end
toc
```

Output -

```
-------------------- For loop NO fuN
Elapsed time is 28.101873 seconds.
-------------------- run run KRON
Elapsed time is 1.156337 seconds.
-------------------- fun fun BSXFUN
Elapsed time is 0.692433 seconds.
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for the benchmark! Seems like I really have to look into bsxfun more carefully :D

Comment: @lhcgeneva I can't stress more for people to look into bsxfun, best thing happened to MATLAB! :)

Comment: Wow thanks! Also on my machine your solution is more or less twice as fast. Have to change the accepted answer, sorry @lhcgeneva :)

Comment: @Simon That's awesome really, thanks for checking back!

Comment: Haha, really good you checked back, that's no problem, you should go for the fastest answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can completely **vectorize** this using [repmat](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html?searchHighlight=repmat), [kron](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) and [reshape](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) or, using Divakar's solution with `bsxfun`, `permute` and `repmat` which gives you another significant improvement in terms of speed.

```
tic
for j = 1:1000
A1 = repmat(A, n, 1);
B1 = kron(B,ones(n,1));
D = reshape(A1(:).*B1(:), n*n, m);
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.117396 seconds.

```
tic
for j = 1:1000
C = zeros(n*n,m);
for i = 1 : m
    tmp = A(:,i) * B(:,i)';
    C(:,i) = tmp(:);
end
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 5.751179 seconds.

So, speedup is about 50 fold. However, as discussed in the comments below, the speedup depends, as usual, on the size of the matrices and the number of times the task is executed.

Comment: Thanks, corrected :) Are you running it 1000 times in a row? I think to get reliable timing the matrix is too small, so I used a loop to get a higher sample size. If I run the same thing 10000 times, I get an even higher speedup, however, if it's only run once the speedup is only 3-5 fold, as you say.

Comment: Thanks! However, my speedup is only 5x at most (3x on average, but still better than nothing). Also, it should be `repmat(A,n,1)` :) 
Also, for large matrices Matlab can run out of memory (I tried with `n = 100` and `m = 1000`).

Comment: I was trying with a short loops (50 iterations) but with larger matrices. You are right, with bigger loops the gain is much higher. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, I guess it depends on your system, mine just took 20 minutes to do n = 1000, m=1000, also note the Memory settings in Matlab and, if you wanna process large matrices it probably makes sense to split things up into chunks that can be processed easily and connect them using a for loop, so a hybrid approach between your original one and mine..